# AS3 sound loading

Tags: actionscript-3

I am using the code below to load an external mp3 file:

```
//Create an instance of the Sound class
var soundClip:Sound=new Sound();

//Create a new SoundChannel Object
var sndChannel:SoundChannel=new SoundChannel();

//Load sound using URLRequest
soundClip.load(new URLRequest("namesounds/agamemnonas.mp3"));

//Create an event listener that wll update once sound has finished loading
soundClip.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onComplete,false,0,true);
function onComplete(evt:Event):void {
    //Play loaded sound
    sndChannel=soundClip.play();
}
```

Also in my html I have a drop down list:

```
<select name="sounds" id="sounds">
  <option value="sounds/eden.mp3" selected="selected">eden</option>
  <option value="sounds/zeus.mp3">zeus</option>
  <option value="sounds/earth.mp3">earth</option>
</select>
```

Is it possible to send a path from a drop down menu to a flash file?
For example:

```
//Load sound using URLRequest
soundClip.load(new URLRequest("namesounds/agamemnonas.mp3"));
```

The URLRequest must be the path from drop down menu list from my .php file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use `ExternalInterface.addCallback` in your AS and call that function from javascript

#### AS3

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback("loadSoundClip", loadSoundClip);
function loadSoundClip(mp3File:String):void{
    soundClip.load(new URLRequest(mp3File));
}
```

#### Pure Javascript

```
// This is the <select>
var sounds = document.getElementById('sounds');
// This is the <object>/<embed>
var flashObject = document.getElementById('flashObject');
sounds.onchange = function(){
    flashObject.loadSoundClip(sounds.options[sounds.selectedIndex].value);
};
```

### OR

#### jQuery

```
// This is the <select>
var sounds = $('#sounds');
// This is the <object>/<embed>
var flashObject = $('#flashObject');
sounds.on('change', function(){
    flashObject[0].loadSoundClip($(this).val());
});
```

**Don't forget to set your `allowscriptaccess` of the `object` / `embed` to the correct value so the page can communicate with the flash object**

Comment: is it possbile to give me an example please, i am dummy with as3. Thanks

Comment: Koen, Must i delete all of my AS3 code so far and replace it with yours? Or must i put your AS3 code somewhere in my AS3 Code?

Comment: Nice but where? hehehehehe!!! if you have a little time tell me where must i add it, Otherwise thank you again for your time!

Comment: The AS3 part just below your existing ActionScript, the Javascript in you PHP file just below the `<select>` between `<script></script>` tags

Comment: Must i remove onComplete function?